# Entity Code First : Two DatabaseInitializer for same DbContext type

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two DbContext : Same type (MyDbContext) but differents connection strings.

I would use differents Database Initializers for them.

Is it possible ?

This is not possible with static generic function:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `using same type` for both `conn` ?

Comment: For two database, but same model structure

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You need to maintain 2 `context` types if you need to initialise db in different ways.But you can abstract away the common entities into separate class and then you can use that common class by using inheritance in your 2 `context` types.After that you can initialise your db as you wish.